# Dúvida sobre mostrar IP da rede local

Tags: java, byte

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para desligar os PC's de um laboratório. Tenho uma referência a classe `InetAddress`, invocando o método `getLocalhost()`. Depois jogo isso em um `array` de byte e depois fiz um `for` pra exibir o IP em sequência.

Porém, como é um `array` de bytes, se o endereço for como no meu caso: 10.248.72.58, ele exibe da seguinte maneira: 10.-8.72.58, por ser byte, a faixa de números que "cabem" vai de -128 a 127(8 bits).

Só que se eu mudar pra `int`, da erro na hora de chamar a função (que retorna byte), por isso o `array` tem que ser de byte.

```
    InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); // Pega o nome do host do sistema,
    //resolvendo pra um objeto InetAddress. Faz cache do endereço por um curto periodo de tempo

    byte[] ip = localhost.getAddress();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println("Ip: " + (byte)ip[i]);

    }
```

Saída: Ip: 10.-8.72.58

Comment: Já tentei fazer o cast do valor dentro do for e não funcionou.

Comment: Usar o `getHostAddress()` não serve pra ti?

Comment: Eu ia sugerir algo mas não sei se no mundo Java seria visto como gambiarra (apesar dos meus pontos na tag eu nunca fiz um programa em Java na vida). Pegar o valor em *byte*, fazer *cast* para inteiro e somar 127.

Comment: @Renan é uma boa solução (se você antes verificar se o número é negativo e somar 256 ao invés de 127). Poderia postar como resposta.

Comment: @Math Acho que somar 256 a um *byte* em java dá o mesmo número original. Se pegarmos os dois extremos: -127 + 127 dá 0 (o menor valor possível para um fragmento de IP). 128 + 127 dá 255 (o maior valor possível).

Comment: @Renan mas a ideia é justamente chegar `no mesmo número original`, não é? Entretanto depois que ele já estiver sendo armazenado em uma variável que suporte mais bits. Faça um teste em C# (ou em qualquer linguagem) apenas para validar a lógica.

Comment: @Math reli a pergunta e vi que minha solução realmente causa confusão e adiciona problemas ao invés de resolvê-los. Valeu!

Answer (score 5):

Você pode transformar o byte de sinalizado para não-sinalizado assim:

```
ip[i] & 0xFFL;
```

Exemplo:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class IP {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); 
        byte[] ip = localhost.getAddress();
        int[] ip2 = new int[ip.length];
        System.out.println("Imprimindo em byte:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Ip: %d ", ip[i] & 0xFFL); //imprime não-sinalizado
            ip2[i] = (int) (ip[i] & 0xFFL); //armazenei já como não-sinalizado em um int[]
        }
        System.out.println("\nImprimindo em int:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Ip: %d ", ip2[i]); //imprime o int não-sinalizado
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> Imprimindo em byte:
>   Ip: 192 Ip: 168 Ip: 239 Ip: 1
>   Imprimindo em int:
>   Ip: 192 Ip: 168 Ip: 239 Ip: 1

Answer (score 4):

Se for apenas para mostrar o IP podes simplesmente usar o método `getHostAddress()`.

```
InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); // Pega o nome do host do sistema,     resolvendo pra um 
// objeto InetAddress. Faz cache do endereço por um curto periodo de tempo

System.out.println("Ip: " + localhost.getHostAddress());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * Contém métodos úteis para o sistema
 *
 * @author msventura@uol.com.br Brasília, 24/08/2017
 */
public class Utils {

    /**
     * Dado um String IP devolve um InetAddress.
     */
    public static InetAddress getInetAddress(String ip) {
        System.out.println("ip = " + ip);

        String[] pedaçoIP = ip.split("[.]");
        if (pedaçoIP.length != 4){
           mostraErro("Utils:getInetAddress():ip mau formado =\"" + ip + "\"" );
        }
        byte[] array = new byte[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int x = Integer.decode(pedaçoIP[i]);
            array[i] = (byte) x;
            /*
            Acima funciona muito bem, mas se tentar assim, é incompatível!
            array[i] = (byte) Integer.decode(pedaçoIP[i]);
            Mas assim também funciona
            array[i] = (byte) ((int)Integer.decode(pedaçoIP[i]));
            */

        }
        InetAddress address = null;
        try {
            address = InetAddress.getByAddress(array);

        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            mostraErro("Utils:getInetAddress():ip=" + ip + "\nex.getMessage="
                    + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return address;
    }

    /**
     * Mostra uma janela com mensagem de erro.
     */
    public static void mostraErro(String mensagem) {
        System.out.println("ERRO: " + mensagem);
        String[] opções = {"OK, Continuar", "Fechar o Programa"};
        int retorno = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, mensagem,
                "OCORREU UM ERRO", 0, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null, opções, 1);

        if (retorno == 1) {
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Testa os métodos fora do seu contexto.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InetAddress address = null;
        address = getInetAddress("127.0.0.1");
        System.out.println("HostAddress = \""+address.getHostAddress()+"\"");
        System.out.println("HostName = \""+address.getCanonicalHostName()+"\"");
        address = getInetAddress("192.168.1.1");
        System.out.println("HostAddress = \""+address.getHostAddress()+"\"");
        System.out.println("HostName = \""+address.getCanonicalHostName()+"\"");
        //mostraErro("Uma mensagem de erro");
    }
}
```

Comment: Toda ajuda é bem-vinda, e é muito boa a iniciativa de um usuário novo já contribuindo com código. Só note que é importante explicar na resposta como é que o tal código é usado, e como ele resolve o problema do que foi perguntado, para que a comunidade possa votar conscientemente em sua resposta, e o autor da pergunta ser beneficiado de fato com o novo conhecimento. Aqui tem umas dicas para um melhor aproveitamento do site: [Answer], [Tour] e [Help]